# SQL-like window functions in PANDAS: Row Numbering in Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I come from a sql background and I use the following data processing step frequently:

1. Partition the table of data by one or more fields
2. For each partition, add a rownumber to each of its rows that ranks the row by one or more other fields, where the analyst specifies ascending or descending

EX:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1' : ['a','a','a','b','a'],
           'data1' : [1,2,2,3,3],
           'data2' : [1,10,2,3,30]})
df
     data1        data2     key1    
0    1            1         a           
1    2            10        a        
2    2            2         a       
3    3            3         b       
4    3            30        a
```

I'm looking for how to do the PANDAS equivalent to this sql window function:

```
RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Key1 ORDER BY Data1 ASC, Data2 DESC)


    data1        data2     key1    RN
0    1            1         a       1    
1    2            10        a       2 
2    2            2         a       3
3    3            3         b       1
4    3            30        a       4
```

I've tried the following which I've gotten to work where there are no 'partitions':

```
def row_number(frame,orderby_columns, orderby_direction,name):
    frame.sort_index(by = orderby_columns, ascending = orderby_direction, inplace = True)
    frame[name] = list(xrange(len(frame.index)))
```

I tried to extend this idea to work with partitions (groups in pandas) but the following didn't work:

```
df1 = df.groupby('key1').apply(lambda t: t.sort_index(by=['data1', 'data2'], ascending=[True, False], inplace = True)).reset_index()

def nf(x):
    x['rn'] = list(xrange(len(x.index)))

df1['rn1'] = df1.groupby('key1').apply(nf)
```

But I just got a lot of NaNs when I do this.

Ideally, there'd be a succinct way to replicate the window function capability of sql (i've figured out the window based aggregates...that's a one liner in pandas)...can someone share with me the most idiomatic way to number rows like this in PANDAS?

Comment: seems like you ought to be able to `.rank` by multiple columns...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this by using `groupby` twice along with the `rank` method:

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby('key1')
```

Use the min method argument to give values which share the same data1 the same RN:

```
In [12]: g['data1'].rank(method='min')
Out[12]:
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    4
dtype: float64

In [13]: df['RN'] = g['data1'].rank(method='min')
```

And then groupby these results and add the rank with respect to data2:

```
In [14]: g1 = df.groupby(['key1', 'RN'])

In [15]: g1['data2'].rank(ascending=False) - 1
Out[15]:
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    0
dtype: float64

In [16]: df['RN'] += g1['data2'].rank(ascending=False) - 1

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   data1  data2 key1  RN
0      1      1    a   1
1      2     10    a   2
2      2      2    a   3
3      3      3    b   1
4      3     30    a   4
```

*It feels like there ought to be a native way to do this (there may well be!...).*

Comment: i agree, ranking by multiple columns seems natural...should I request it on github?

Comment: @AndyHayden To get the behaviour of `row_number()`, you should pass `method='first'`, not `method='min'` (that gives you `rank()` behaviour).

Answer (score 118):

you can also use `sort_values()`, `groupby()` and finally `cumcount() + 1`:

```
df['RN'] = df.sort_values(['data1','data2'], ascending=[True,False]) \
             .groupby(['key1']) \
             .cumcount() + 1
print(df)
```

yields:

```
   data1  data2 key1  RN
0      1      1    a   1
1      2     10    a   2
2      2      2    a   3
3      3      3    b   1
4      3     30    a   4
```

PS tested with pandas 0.18

Comment: Just tried this method and got the following warning: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @AndrewL, your `df` seems to be a "copy copy of a slice of a DF"... does the following command work for your `df`: `df['new'] = 0` __without__ this warning?

Comment: thanks for your insight. The above command actually does work without throwing the warning. Can you explain how this "copy of a slice of a DF" is problematic and why it's handled differently than a regular df? Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewL, there is a link in this warning with an explanation - i don't think i can explain it better

Comment: @maxU if you apply sort_values() before the groupby the sorting happens irrespective of 'key1'. But in original window function the expectation is to sort within the key space of 'key1'

Comment: Getting "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis". Any help?

Comment: @lacrima, i think you should open a new question and post there a small __reproducible__ sample dataset and your desired dataset.

Comment: @MaxU I have created this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55421932/sqlish-window-function-in-python
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 42):

Use groupby.rank function.
Here the working example.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'C2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df

C1 C2
a  1
a  2
a  3
b  4
b  5

df["RANK"] = df.groupby("C1")["C2"].rank(method="first", ascending=True)
df

C1 C2 RANK
a  1  1
a  2  2
a  3  3
b  4  1
b  5  2
```

Comment: Nice elegant up-to-date answer to an old question.

Comment: This is a nice solution if you only need only a single column to ORDER BY, but not for multiple columns (which is why the accepted answer is more convoluted).

Answer (score 23):

You can use `transform` and `Rank` together Here is an example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1' : ['a','a','a','b','b'],
           'C2' : [1,2,3,4,5]})
df['Rank'] = df.groupby(by=['C1'])['C2'].transform(lambda x: x.rank())
df
```

[image]

Have a look at Pandas Rank method for more information

Comment: This is as close to a SQL like window functionality as it gets in Pandas. Can also just pass in the pandas Rank function instead wrapping it in lambda. `df.groupby(by=['C1'])['C2'].transform(pd.DataFrame.rank)`

Comment: To get the behaviour of `row_number()`, you should pass `method='first'` to the `rank` function. Similarly, for `rank()` and `dense_rank()`, you should pass `method='min'` and `method='dense'` respectively. Incidentally, that's actually why a lambda function is necessary here @timle

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.lib.fast_zip()` can create a tuple array from a list of array. You can use this function to create a tuple series, and then rank it:

```
values = {'key1' : ['a','a','a','b','a','b'],
          'data1' : [1,2,2,3,3,3],
          'data2' : [1,10,2,3,30,20]}

df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=list("abcdef"))

def rank_multi_columns(df, cols, **kw):
    data = []
    for col in cols:
        if col.startswith("-"):
            flag = -1
            col = col[1:]
        else:
            flag = 1
        data.append(flag*df[col])
    values = pd.lib.fast_zip(data)
    s = pd.Series(values, index=df.index)
    return s.rank(**kw)

rank = df.groupby("key1").apply(lambda df:rank_multi_columns(df, ["data1", "-data2"]))

print rank
```

the result:

```
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    2
e    4
f    1
dtype: float64
```