# SQLish window function in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do something like an SQL window function in Python 3.6. I have created the following code which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775935/sql-like-window-functions-in-pandas-row-numbering-in-python-pandas-dataframe/36704460?noredirect=1#comment97561954_36704460), but I'm getting the following error:

> "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['daeb21718d5a','daeb21718d5a','daeb21718d5a'],
           'product_id' : [123,456,789],
           'probability' : [0.076838,0.053384, 0.843900 ]})

df['rank'] = df.sort_values(['probability'], ascending=False) \
               .groupby(['id']) \
               .cumcount() + 1
```

---

Weirdly if I add `.reset_index(drop=True)` before grouping, the error is fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis\` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236275/what-does-valueerror-cannot-reindex-from-a-duplicate-axis-mean)

Comment: What is your expected output? Which column are you trying to give a rank?

Comment: what Pandas version are you using? Your code works just fine for me (Pandas 0.24.2)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, your code works fine on my machine. (`pandas.__version__` is 0.23.4)

Comment: @MaxU  I am using exactly the same version as you.

Comment: @lacrima, and you are getting mentioned error when executing the code from your question?? Try to open a new Python terminal/iPython/Jupyter and execute the code from your question...

Comment: Still getting the same error. The weird thing is that if I remove the sort_values and use rank instead, like@Erfan suggested, it works. So I guess there is something weird with the sort_values method

Comment: @lacrima, no wonder you didn't get really helpful answer - you didn't provide a __reproducible__ sample data set.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to rank `probability` descending based on each group of `id`.

You were almost there, the following will solve your problem:

```
df['rank'] = df.sort_values(['probability'], ascending=False) \
             .groupby(['id'])['probability'] \
             .cumcount() + 1

print(df)
             id  product_id  probability  rank
0  daeb21718d5a         123     0.076838     2
1  daeb21718d5a         456     0.053384     3
2  daeb21718d5a         789     0.843900     1
```

Or we can use pandas `.rank` method for this:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('id')['probability'].rank(ascending=False)

print(df)
             id  product_id  probability  rank
0  daeb21718d5a         123     0.076838   2.0
1  daeb21718d5a         456     0.053384   3.0
2  daeb21718d5a         789     0.843900   1.0
```