# Translating conditional RANK Window-Function from SQL to Pandas

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I’m trying to translate a window-function from SQL to Pandas, which is only applied under the condition, that a match is possible – otherwise a NULL (None) value is inserted.

**SQL-Code** (example)

```
SELECT 
    [ID_customer]
    [cTimestamp]
    [TMP_Latest_request].[ID_req] AS [ID of Latest request]
FROM [table].[Customer] AS [Customer]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT [ID_req], [ID_customer], [rTimestamp], 
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID_customer ORDER BY rTimestamp DESC) as rnk
        FROM [table].[Customer_request]
    ) AS [Q]
    WHERE rnk = 1
) AS [TMP_Latest_request]
ON [Customer].[ID_customer] = [TMP_Latest_request].[ID_customer]
```

**Example**

Joining the ID of the latest customer request (if exists) to the customer.

```
table:Customer
+-------------+------------+
| ID_customer | cTimestamp |
+-------------+------------+
|           1 |       2014 |
|           2 |       2014 |
|           3 |       2015 |
+-------------+------------+

table: Customer_request
+--------+-------------+------------+
| ID_req | ID_customer | rTimestamp |
+--------+-------------+------------+
|      1 |           1 |       2012 |
|      2 |           1 |       2013 |
|      3 |           1 |       2014 |
|      4 |           2 |       2014 |
+--------+-------------+------------+

Result: table:merged
+-------------+------------+----------------------+
| ID_customer | cTimestamp | ID of Latest request |
+-------------+------------+----------------------+
|           1 |       2014 | 3                    |
|           2 |       2014 | 4                    |
|           3 |       2015 | None/NULL            |
+-------------+------------+----------------------+
```

What is the equivalent in Python Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `RANK()` function, you can simply using the below, and it is easy to convert.

```
SELECT A.ID_Customer,A.cTimeStamp,B.ID_req
FROM Customer A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID_Customer,MAX(ID_req)ID_req 
    FROM Customer_request
    GROUP BY ID_Customer
   )B
ON A.ID_Customer = B.ID_Customer
```

Try the following query, if you are facing any issues, ask me in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This will work with this simple example, but won't work with more sophisticated utilizations of the RANK. For example, if I have a list of certain rank values I want to match on, except of just the MAX value.

Comment: @Nex, Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775935/sql-like-window-functions-in-pandas-row-numbering-in-python-pandas-dataframe