# Add rank column in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rank

In the code below I am trying to get top 250 records based on imdb_score and then populate rank to it based on its score. Note I need to populate rank from 1 to 250. All the records will have different rank values. I am getting NaN as value for all rows. Please help.

---

```
IMDb_Top_250['rank'] = IMDb_Top_250.nlargest(250,'imdb_score').apply(lambda x: range(1,250))
```

Comment: show sample of you data and working example

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775935/sql-like-window-functions-in-pandas-row-numbering-in-python-pandas-dataframe

Comment: IIUC try only `IMDb_Top_250.nlargest(250,'imdb_score')` or `IMDb_Top_250.nlargest(250,'imdb_score')['imdb_score']` i didn't see any need of apply here