# How to create a duplicate flag (column) that counts duplicate rows based on two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, duplicates

I have the following dataframe and would like to create a column at the end called "dup" showing the number of times the row shows up based on the "Seasons" and "Actor" columns. Ideally the dup column would look like this:

```
               Name  Seasons        Actor   dup
0   Stranger Things        3       Millie     1
1   Game of Thrones        8       Emilia     1
2  La Casa De Papel        4       Sergio     1     
3         Westworld        3  Evan Rachel     1
4   Stranger Things        3       Millie     2
5  La Casa De Papel        4       Sergio     1
```

Comment: Do you want the duplicate row to be present in the dataframe?

Comment: Line at Index 5 correct, is that supposed to be 2 instead of 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
df['dup'] = df.groupby(['Seasons', 'Actor']).cumcount() + 1
```

Output:

```
               Name  Seasons        Actor  dup
0   Stranger Things        3       Millie    1
1   Game of Thrones        8       Emilia    1
2  La Casa De Papel        4       Sergio    1
3         Westworld        3  Evan Rachel    1
4   Stranger Things        3       Millie    2
5  La Casa De Papel        4       Sergio    2
```

As Scott Boston mentioned, according to your criteria the last row should also be `2` in the `dup` column.

Here is a similar post that can provide you more information. [SQL-like window functions in PANDAS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36704460/8785917)