# Check a value against row below, return if current row is the first unique value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, row

Dear stackoverflow friends,
I need your help from senior pandas users for a pretty easy task that I cannot it solve myself.

here's a df with recorded entrance for every person, however, there are **multiple** ins for people (*they get in- check out for lunchbreak- get in again*).

The df is sorted ascending for people, date and entrance time.

I need to extract the 1st recorded entrance, thus excluding the others (eg: after lunchbreak).
To get to the desired output *(1st_stamp)* i need to check whether the current row is the first in of the day ( of the same person ofc), then a "y" would appear on column "1st_stamp".

It's tricky because some people have only 1 entrance (eg: Person N.3), some have 2 (Person N.2), and some split their lunch in two breaks so they have 3 in-recorded entrances (Person N. 7).

How would you go on solving this riddle?

*Ps:being able to clean this data is of enormous use for staff planning processes.
Thank you dears :)*

```
+-------------+------------+------------------+----------+-----------+
|    name     |    Date    |      start       |  tstart  | 1st_stamp |
+-------------+------------+------------------+----------+-----------+
| Person N. 1 | 13/08/2020 | 13/08/2020 07:00 | 07:00:00 | y         |
| Person N. 1 | 13/08/2020 | 13/08/2020 13:10 | 13:10:00 | n         |
| Person N. 2 | 13/08/2020 | 13/08/2020 10:00 | 10:00:00 | y         |
| Person N. 2 | 13/08/2020 | 13/08/2020 13:46 | 13:46:00 | n         |
| Person N. 3 | 13/08/2020 | 13/08/2020 09:00 | 09:00:00 | y         |
| Person N. 4 | 13/08/2020 | 13/08/2020 08:00 | 08:00:00 | y         |
| Person N. 4 | 13/08/2020 | 13/08/2020 13:04 | 13:04:00 | n         |
| Person N. 4 | 13/08/2020 | NaT              | NaT      | n         |
| Person N. 5 | 13/08/2020 | 13/08/2020 10:00 | 10:00:00 | y         |
| Person N. 6 | 13/08/2020 | 13/08/2020 07:00 | 07:00:00 | y         |
| Person N. 6 | 13/08/2020 | 13/08/2020 13:29 | 13:29:00 | n         |
| Person N. 7 | 13/08/2020 | 13/08/2020 08:00 | 08:00:00 | y         |
| Person N. 7 | 13/08/2020 | 13/08/2020 14:01 | 14:01:00 | n         |
| Person N. 7 | 13/08/2020 | 13/08/2020 16:00 | 16:00:00 | n         |
+-------------+------------+------------------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to create 1st_stamp column right?

To create `1st_stamp` column, here is one way to approach:

```
# 1. Convert to datetime if it isn't already
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])

# 2. Partition data by name and rank them based on start datetime 
df['order'] = df.groupby('name')['start'].rank(method='min')

# 3. Create a variable to indicate if it's the earliest instance
df['1st_stamp'] = np.where(df['order']==1, 'y', 'n')
df
```

2nd step is copied from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775935/sql-like-window-functions-in-pandas-row-numbering-in-python-pandas-dataframe).

This will create the `order` column - if you don't need it, you can just delete it with `del(df['order'])`.

Comment: I owe you a beer when you will be visiting Rome!

Comment: Haha, thanks Arci for the kind gesture. All good. Glad it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the column is a datetime;

`df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])`

Return the first time you can do something like;

`df.groupby(['name', 'Date', 'tstart']).first()`

Or first time and the count of entries;

`grouped = df.groupby(['name', 'Date', 'tstart']).agg({'tstart': ['min', 'count']})`