# Index Error: Columns status already selected

Tags: python, dataframe

have a data frame data as below

```
   InsuranceId InsuranceStatus  Date
0  Ins1234     DuePayment       2020-06-07 23:59:43.123456+00:00
1  Ins1234     Successful       2019-06-07 23:59:43.123456+00:00
2  Ins1234     Successful       2018-06-07 23:59:43.123456+00:00
3  Ins5678     DuePayment       2020-07-07 22:59:32.123421+00:00
4  Ins5678     Successful       2019-07-07 22:59:32.123421+00:00
5  Ins5678     Successful       2018-07-07 22:59:32.123421+00:00
```

trying to create a rownumber/rank on basis of group by InsuranceId and max(Date)

```
df['RowNum'] = df.groupby('InsuranceId')['InsuranceStatus']['Date'].rank(method="first", ascending=True)

and 

df['RowNum'] = df.groupby(by=['InsuranceId'])['InsuranceStatus']['Date'].transform(lambda x: x.rank())
```

by referring [SQL-like window functions in PANDAS: Row Numbering in Python Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775935/sql-like-window-functions-in-pandas-row-numbering-in-python-pandas-dataframe)

```
Error: Index Error: Columns status already selected
```

trying to achieve below output

```
   InsuranceId InsuranceStatus  Date                                RowNum
0  Ins1234     DuePayment       2020-06-07 23:59:43.123456+00:00    1
1  Ins1234     Successful       2019-06-07 23:59:43.123456+00:00    2
2  Ins1234     Successful       2018-06-07 23:59:43.123456+00:00    3
3  Ins5678     DuePayment       2020-07-07 22:59:32.123421+00:00    1
4  Ins5678     Successful       2019-07-07 22:59:32.123421+00:00    2
5  Ins5678     Successful       2018-07-07 22:59:32.123421+00:00    3
```

Is there anything i am missing to add. pls any suggestions

Final output:

```
   InsuranceId InsuranceStatus  Date                                
   Ins1234     DuePayment       2020-06-07 23:59:43.123456+00:00    
   Ins5678     DuePayment       2020-07-07 22:59:32.123421+00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html#pandas-dataframe-rank). Just pass the value you want to do group by and rank the column which needs to be ranked.

```
df['Rank'] = df.groupby(by=['InsuranceId'])['Date'].rank(method='max',ascending=False)
df[df['Rank']==1]
```

**Output:**

```
InsuranceId InsuranceStatus  Date                                
Ins1234     DuePayment       2020-06-07 23:59:43.123456+00:00    
Ins5678     DuePayment       2020-07-07 22:59:32.123421+00:00
```

Comment: Its not working.. I tried this earlier , but again getting an error: Type Error

Comment: It works as expected you can see [here](https://repl.it/repls/SorrowfulKosherLead#main.py)