# Pandas Dataframe - add column which shows row count satisfying condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C']})
df
```

|  | item |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | B |
| 5 | B |
| 6 | C |

I want to add `entrynum` column which shows rownumber for each item starting from 1, so for my dataframe to look like this:

|  | item | entrynum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1 |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 2 | B | 1 |
| 3 | B | 2 |
| 4 | B | 3 |
| 5 | B | 4 |
| 6 | C | 1 |

I can iterate Pandas dataframe row by row and if `item` value changed set `entrynum` value equal to `1` otherwise set `entrynum` equal to previous `entrynum` value plus `1`. But I wonder if a better solution exists?

I'm thinking what I want is similar to SQL window functions but I don't understand how to provide partition by `item`.

Comment: You may want to check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775935/sql-like-window-functions-in-pandas-row-numbering-in-python-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby item and cumulatively count entities in each group. Store the output in the entrance column.

```
 df['entrynum']=df.groupby('item').cumcount()+1
```

Comment: @ppwater,  thanks I should have as a matter of course given an explanation. Apologies.