# How do I do a SQL-like window function in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, window-functions

I have data that looks like the following:

| org_id | org_name | person_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Microsoft | 453241 | 1/1/05 |
| 222 | Zebra | 21341 | 6/1/95 |
| 333 | Company | 42343241 | 1/1/23 |
| 111 | Microsoft | 098678 | 2/1/13 |
| 111 | Microsoft Inc | 6786 | 6/1/23 |
| 222 | Zebra | 546 | 4/1/06 |
| 333 | Company | vcxv313 | 2/1/23 |
| 222 | NewZebra | 876 | 4/1/23 |
| 333 | Company | 432gf | 4/1/23 |

And I want to run Pandas functions similar to this type of SQL query:

```
SELECT org_id, org_name
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY org_id ORDER BY date DESC) as row_num,
org_id, org_name
FROM dataframe
)
WHERE row_num = 1
```

result set should be:

| org_id | org_name |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | Microsoft Inc |
| 222 | NewZebra |
| 333 | Company |

I'm finding myself having trouble with the Pandas groupby syntax and aggregate functions. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL-like window functions in PANDAS: Row Numbering in Python Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775935/sql-like-window-functions-in-pandas-row-numbering-in-python-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

In pandas we can sort the dataframe by date in desc order then drop the duplicates

```
df['date_'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%y')
result = (
    df
    .sort_values('date_', ascending=False)
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['org_id'])
    .reindex(columns=['org_id', 'org_name'])
)
```

---

```
   org_id       org_name
4     111  Microsoft Inc
7     222       NewZebra
8     333        Company
```